# Struggling with implementing Set with linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, set

My task is to implement a set with a linked list. I created the linked list pretty quickly and then started to build set. I struggled a little with the set operations (union/intersection/difference) but After implementation i tried to make a driver method and now i am getting a seg fault with contains/add. I cannot properly check my operations as  result. I do not understand why i am getting this error. I am overlooking something...any help would be appreciated.

Linklist.h

```
class ListNode
{

private:
    ListNode* prev;
    ListNode* next;
    int data;

public:
    ListNode() { prev = next = NULL;
    data=0;}
    ListNode(int d, ListNode* p, ListNode* n) { data = d; prev = p; next = n; }

    friend class List;
};

class List
{
private:
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;

public:
    List() { head = tail = NULL; }
    ~List();

    bool isEmpty() { return head == NULL; }
    bool contains(int value);

    void addToHead(int value);
    void addToTail(int value);

    int removeHead();
    int removeTail();

    int removeAt(int index);
    bool remove(int value);

    int at(int index);
    int valueOf(const ListNode* elem);
    const ListNode* getNext(const ListNode* node);
    const ListNode* getPrevious(const ListNode* node);
    const ListNode* getHead() { return head; }
    const ListNode* getTail() { return tail; }

    void print();
};

List::~List()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
        removeTail();
}

bool List::contains(int value)
{
    ListNode *tmp = head;  // <**This is where error occurs**
    while (tmp != NULL && tmp->data != value)
        tmp = tmp->next;

    return tmp != NULL;
}

void List::addToHead(int value)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        head = tail = new ListNode(value, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        head = new ListNode(value, NULL, head);
        head->next->prev = head;
    }
}

void List::addToTail(int value)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        head = tail = new ListNode(value, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        tail = new ListNode(value, tail, NULL);
        tail->prev->next = tail;
    }
}

int List::removeHead()
{
    int value = head->data;
    if (head == tail)
    {
        delete tail;
        head = tail = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        head = head->next;
        delete head->prev;
        head->prev = NULL;
    }

    return value;
}

int List::removeTail()
{
    int value = head->data;
    if (head == tail)
    {
        delete tail;
        head = tail = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        tail = tail->prev;
        delete tail->next;
        tail->next = NULL;
    }

    return value;
}



int List::removeAt(int index)
{

//    Remove the node at index. Return the int value contained at
//    the now removed node. Exit program if an invalid 
    ListNode *temp = head;
    int i=0;
    if (index == 0) {
        removeHead();
    }
    while (temp != NULL && i < index-1) {
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
    if (temp == NULL || temp -> next == NULL ) {
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        ListNode* temp2 = temp->next;
        temp->next = temp->next->next;
        temp2->next = NULL;
        delete temp2; }
}

bool List::remove(int value)
{

//    Remove the provided value if it is contained in the list. Return true if the
//        value was found and remove, return false if no changes were made to the list
    ListNode *prev = head;
    ListNode* temp = head->next;

    if (prev->data==value){
       removeHead();
    }
else {
        while (temp != NULL && temp->data != value) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if (temp == NULL) {
            cout << "No change" << endl;
            return false;
        } else {
            prev->next = temp->next; // unlink the node you remove
            delete temp; // delete the node
        }
    }
}

int List::at(int index)
{
//    Returns the int value contained at the node at the provided index. Exit program if
//        an invalid index is provided
    ListNode *temp = head;
    for(int i=1; i < index; i++) {
        if (temp -> next == NULL){
            exit(1);
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return valueOf(temp);
}


int List::valueOf(const ListNode* elem)
{

    return elem->data;
}

const ListNode* List::getNext(const ListNode* node)
{

    return node->next;
}

const ListNode* List::getPrevious(const ListNode* node)
{

    return node->prev;
}

void List::print() {

    ListNode *tmp = head;
    if (tmp != NULL) {
        do {
            if (tmp != NULL) {
                cout << tmp->data << " -> ";
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        } while (tmp != NULL);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
#endif //UNTITLED4_LIST_H
```

Set

```
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"

using namespace std;

class Set
{
private:
    List* list;
    int set_size;
public:
    Set();
    ~Set();

    bool contains(int value);
    bool add(int value);
    bool remove(int value);
    void clear();

    Set* set_union(Set&);
    Set* intersection(Set&);
    Set* difference(Set&);

    void print();
    int size() { return set_size; }
};

    Set::Set() {
        list = NULL;
        set_size = 0;
    }

    Set::~Set() {
        delete list;
        set_size = 0;
    }

    bool Set::contains(int value) {
        // Returns a boolean value representing if the provided int value is contained
        //in the list
        if(list->contains(value)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            list->addToHead(value);
            set_size++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    bool Set::add(int value) {
    //    Returns a boolean value representing if the provided int value was successfully
    //    added to the list do not allow duplicate


        if (!contains(value))
        { list->addToTail(value);}

        else {return false;}

    }

    bool Set::remove(int value) {

      return  list->remove(value);
    }

    void Set::clear() {
    //This function should assign 0 to set_size, and delete list.
        set_size = 0;
        delete list;
    }

    Set *Set::set_union(Set &s) {
        //Creates and returns a Set pointer that contains the set union of the
        //invoking Set object and a second Set object passed into the function
        Set *temp = new Set();

        for(int t= 1;t<s.set_size; t++)
           temp->add(s.list->at(t));

        return  temp;

    }

    Set *Set::intersection(Set &s) {
    //    Creates and returns a Set pointer that contains the set intersection of the
    //    invoking Set object and a second Set object passed into the function.
        Set *temp = new Set();
        for ( int i = 0; i < set_size; i++) {
            if (s.contains(list->at(i))) {
                temp->add(list->at(i));
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    Set *Set::difference(Set &s) {
    //    Creates and returns a Set pointer that contains the set difference between
    //    the invoking Set object and a second Set object passed into the function. The
    //    invoking Set object should be considered the set that is being subtracted from (
    //    Invoking Set – Parameter Set)

        Set *temp = new Set();
        for ( int i = 0; i < set_size; i++) {
            if (s.contains(list->at(i))) {
                temp->add(list->at(i));
            }
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < set_size; i++){
            if (temp->contains(list->at(i))) {
                s.remove(list->at(i));
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    void Set::print() {
    //    TO DO --- Already have print in list

    }

    int main() {
        int choice, item, size1, size2;
        cout << "Please Enter the starting Value of Set#1:";
        cin >> size1;
        Set set1;
        cout << "\nPlease Enter the starting Value of Set#2:";
        cin >> size2;
        Set set2;

        cout << "\n Enter " << size2 << " numbers in Set1:";
        for (int i = 1; i < size1; i++) {
            cin >> item;
            set1.add(item);
        }

        cout << "\n Enter " << size2 << " numbers in Set2:";
        for (int i = 1; i < size1; i++) {
            cin >> item;
            set2.add(item);
        }

        while (choice !=7) {
            cout << "1.Insert Element into the Set" << endl;
            cout << "2.Delete Element of the Set" << endl;
            cout << "3.Size of the Set" << endl;
            cout << "4.Union of Set" << endl;
            cout << "5.intersections of set" << endl;
            cout << "6.difference of set" << endl;
            cout << "7.Exit" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your Choice: ";
            cin >> choice;
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    cout << "Enter value to be inserted: ";
                    cin >> item;
                    // st.insert(item);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Enter the element to be deleted: ";
                    cin >> item;
                    //st.erase(item);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "Size of the Set1: ";
                    cout << set1.size() << endl;
                    cout << "\nSize of the Set2: ";
                    cout << set2.size() << endl;

                    break;
                case 4:

                    break;
                case 5:

                    break;
                case 6:
                    exit(1);
                default:
                    cout << "Wrong Choice" << endl;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: First things first.  Please tell us which lines of code have the problem.  Sets don't store duplicates, so you need logic which can add an item to the linked list iff the list doesn't already contain that item.

Comment: Srry thought i added the comment in code stating where the error was. Line 52 of list. Edited to show it now.

Comment: Step one: don’t use pointers unless you really need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Set object holds a pointer to a `List` (Linked list), which is assigned to `NULL` in the `Set` constructor, but no memory for this `List` is ever allocated. This is the reason why every time you attempt to do operations on that `List`, your application segfaults.

You either need to:

- Review whether this list needs to be allocated on the heap (Have the `Set` hold a `List` instead of a `List*`)
- Properly allocate memory for the `List` (*With `new`*) held in your `Set` object.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it for me, it also led me to a couple other bugs but i should be able to handle them.